# Spark dataframe groupBy and further count aggregations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, aggregation

Dataframe example:

```
col_1, col_2
aaa, 1
aaa, 0
bbb, 1
bbb, 1
bbb, 1
```

I'd like to have a resulting df with 3 columns: col_1, total count of rows for that, and count of rows where col_2 === 1.

I've tried

```
df.groupBy($"col_1")
   .agg(count($"col_2" === 1).as("delayed"), count(lit(1)) as "total").show(100)
```

Why total is calculated correctly, but delayed is not?

Comment: I know another ways to achieve this, but my question is why I'm getting wrong result using this approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

When you use `count($"col_2" === 1).as("delayed")`

It is referencing to [count function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#count-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-)

> > `public static Column count(Column e)
> >     Aggregate function: returns the number of items in a group.
> >     Parameters:
> >         e - (undocumented)
> >     Returns:
> >         (undocumented)
> >     Since:
> >         1.3.0`

rather than [scala count function](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/List.html#count%28%28A%29%3D%3EBoolean%29)

> > `def count(p : (A) => Boolean) : Int
> >         Count the number of elements in the list which satisfy a predicate.
> >     Parameters
> >         p - the predicate for which to count
> >     Returns
> >         the number of elements satisfying the predicate p.`

**So the condition inside `count($"col_2" === 1)` i.e. `$"col_2" === 1` is not treated as *true* or *false* but as a column.** Thus the count function simply counts column `$"col_2" === 1`.

I hope the explanation is clear and understandable.

**Solution**

You should *use `when` function to change the value to 1 or 0* and *use `sum` function as a count*.

```
sum(when($"col_2" === 1, 1).otherwise(0)).as("delayed")
```

**If c*ol_2 column* is always *0 or 1* then you can use `sum` only**

```
sum($"col_2").as("delayed")
```

Answer (score 0):

The column `$"col2"===1` still has the same number of elements as `$"col2"`, they're just either `true` or `false`. Instead, you want to convert to integers and sum. (Of course, if the values of col2 are always 1 or 0, you can just sum directly.)

I think you have to define a udf to convert the boolean to integers:

```
val toInt = udf((x: Boolean) => if(x) 1 else 0)
```

Then (I didn't name my columns):

```
scala> df.groupBy($"_1").agg(sum(toInt($"_2"===1)), count($"_2")).show()
+---+------------------+---------+
| _1|sum(UDF((_2 = 1)))|count(_2)|
+---+------------------+---------+
|aaa|                 1|        2|
|bbb|                 3|        3|
+---+------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Interesting thing is that these 2 counts are not equal

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean. I think you might be conflating "count" and "count if", and `count` only counts.

Comment: I'll add more details with concrete numbers later